# handling event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following which works fine in Chrome 22  but is giving me an error in Firefox 16:

```
$('#search-query').on('keyup',function(){
  e=window.event;
  if(e.keyCode===13){
    alert('that was a return');
  }
```

How would I make this work in a cross-browser way?

thx

Comment: Pass `event` as parameter, that's how jQuery normalizes the event for all browsers.

Comment: jQuery also normalizes `e.which`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jQuery wrapper event. firefox don't support `window.event`

```
$('#search-query').on('keyup',function(e){

  if(e.keyCode===13){
    alert('that was a return');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not support `window.event` 
Try this instead

```
$('#search-query').on('keyup',function(e){
  var evt = e || window.event;
  var keyPressed = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  if(keyPressed ===13){
    alert('that was a return');
  }
});
```